# Anyone know why i keep getting this error when i use this component?

Tags: reactjs, npm, jsx

Every time I place this `Ratings Component` in my code it breaks my site. But I need the system can someone help me.

When I use the rating imported from `StarRating/>` it breaks my site and shows this error message. [package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rating)

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `StarRating`.

**Code:**

```
export default function FullWidthTabs(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  function handleChange(event, newValue) {
    setValue(newValue);
  }

  function handleChangeIndex(index) {
    setValue(index);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="fullWidth"
          aria-label="full width tabs example"
        >
          <Tab
            label={props.product.reviews ? 'Reviews' : 'No Reviews'}
            {...a11yProps(0)}
          />
          <Tab label="Write A Review" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <SwipeableViews
        axis={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'x-reverse' : 'x'}
        index={value}
        onChangeIndex={handleChangeIndex}
      >
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0} dir={theme.direction}>
          {props.product.reviews.map((review, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i}>
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemAvatar>
                    <Avatar className={classes.orangeAvatar}>
                      {review.name.charAt(0)}
                    </Avatar>
                  </ListItemAvatar>
                  <ListItemText>
                    <div className="text-center">
                      <small>{review.date}</small>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-center">
                      {<i className={`fas fa-flag`}> {review.country}</i>}
                    </div>
                    <div id="reviewName">
                      <span>{review.name} </span>

                      <br />
                      <small style={{ color: 'green' }}>Verified Buyer</small>
                      <br />
                    </div>
                    <b>{review.title}</b>

                    <br />
                    {review.reviewMessage}
                  </ListItemText>

                </ListItem>
                ** <StarRating /> **
                        </div>
            );
          })}
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1} dir={theme.direction}>
          Item Two
                    </TabPanel>
      </SwipeableViews>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the library im importing into StarRating

```
import React from 'react';
var Rating = require('react-rating');

const StarRating = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Rating />
    </div>
  );
};

export default StarRating;
```

Comment: Did you import StarRating component correctly?

Comment: Why you are using ```require('react-rating');``` instead of ```import Rating from 'react-rating';``` ?

Comment: That is what it says via documentation

Comment: Yes I did import it correctly

Comment: Usage
Require the Rating Component

var Rating = require('react-rating');   From Documentation

Comment: I don't think your imported it correctly. Can you create a codesandbox:?I tried your code without the `FullWidthTab` component and  it works. check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-kilby-g98go

Comment: I think it may be the fullwidth tab library :(

Comment: I copied and pasted your exact component and it is still not working

Comment: @Hoblar there's a typo in Morlo's sandbox, StarRating !== StartRating, so if you simply copy/paste it probably won't work.